# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs: Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsStorage' does not exist

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Ok, this is really frustrating. I have a simple EventHubTrigger Azure function. I keep getting the error: `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs: Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsStorage' does not exist.`

But it does!

Here is my local.settings.json file:

```
{
  "Environment": "Dev",
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    //"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "SensorEventConnectionString": "XYZ",
    "AlertEventConnectionString": "ABC"
  },
 
  "MMG": {
    "APIKey": "xXX",
    "API": "YYY"
  },

  "SendGrid": {
    "Key": "XXX"
  },

  "Database": {
    "SQLServer": "XXX",
    "Cosmos": "XXX"
  },

  "Host": {
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

I am currently only running locally to test this guy out. All of my nuget packages are up to date... super frustrating.

Someone else mentioned they had the issue when their local.settings.json was in their gitignore, but I double checked that... mine isn't in there.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh... ok, so the issue was that somehow... I am sure I did something stupid, but my local.settings.json file wasn't being referenced.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
```

When I added it back all was well.